# How to include view helper in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, helper

I have a module with a custom view helper. Actually it uses the modified code of link_to helper. Just append a query string to the generated link. I have existing tests which fails because the custom helper cannot be found. How can I include it so it is available for RSpec? I tried the following approaches:

1.Using include:

```
describe MyClass do
  include MyHelper
```

2.Using configure

```
RSpec.configure  do |config|
 config.include MyHelper
end
```

3.Adding it in spec_helper.rb

```
   config.include MyHelper
```

Here is the error:

```
1) Mailer#calendar_item_notification should send email for task
 Failure/Error: expect {Mailer.calendar_item_notification('User', @user.id).deliver}.to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(1)
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `<<' for #<Proc:0x00000013102d28>
 # ./app/helpers/mailer_helper.rb:88:in `link_username'
 # ./app/views/user_mailer/calendar_item_notification.html.erb:137:in `_app_views_user_mailer_calendar_item_notification_html_erb___206027131771876632_159436760'
 # ./app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:136:in `calendar_item_notification'
 # ./spec/mailers/user_mailer_spec.rb:19:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/mailers/user_mailer_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/support/misc.rb:13:in `block in suppress_output'
 # ./spec/support/misc.rb:12:in `tap'
 # ./spec/support/misc.rb:12:in `suppress_output'
 # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Thanks

Comment: Can we see the context from which the spec is failing?  Whether the custom helper is invoked in the 'expected' or 'actual' side is relevant.

Comment: Yes, I updated the question

Comment: Is `app/helpers/mailer_helper.rb` the helper you're intending to test?

Comment: Actually I'm not trying to test the helper method. I just want to make it available for other tests. Right now existing tests doesn't pass because link_username cannot be found.

Comment: The error you have supplied indicates that your helper is being loaded, the `link_username` method is found, but on line 88 in your implementation, you call `<<` on a `Proc` variable instead of (presumably) an enumeration.  Consider this possibility or supply an alternative error?

Comment: @Hristo, Are you using the helper in a `feature` spec or `controller`spec?

Comment: Actually @JimVanFleet is right. My question totally does not make sense. The problem was with my helper. There is a variable which is Proc and I though it was a string. This happens when block is used. Disregard my question.